# How do I search for a specific Outlook email in python

Tags: python, email, outlook, python-2.x

I have the following code which works, it can read the most recent Email in my outlook inbox and print the body of that message. However, I want to be able to specify a static Email address, and return all of the messages from that person. How would I change the code to do that?

```python
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.Getlast
body_content = message.body
print body_content
```

I figured it would be as easy as changing 'messages.Getlast' to something like 'messages.Get('Email address here') but no luck with that.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

You have already a script that allow you to obtain the list of message in a folder :

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
```

Once you got all the messages, you just have to check if the message sender is the same :

```
sender = "my_sender"
sender = sender.lower()
for message in messages:
    if sender in message.sender.lower():
        # This message was send by sender
        print message.body
```

That code should print the body of every `message in messages` where `sender` is contained in `message.sender`.

I have add the `lower()` function to avoid problems with caps. You might want to remove it.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Never iterate over all messages in a folder. This is like having a SELECT clause in SQL without WHERE.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line

```
messages = inbox.Items
```

with

```
messages = inbox.Items.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress]='user@domain.demo'")
```

You can then iterate over all messages in the `messages` ([Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items) object) collection. See [Item.Restrict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict) and [Items.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.find) help topics.

Also note that `GetLast` (or `GetFirst`) will not give you the last (by received time) message - the `Items` collection sort order is undetermined unless you explicitly call [Items.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort) specifying some sort criteria.